# How to combine boxplot figures into one?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science, boxplot

I am working now on plot my dataset by boxplot as in below code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
fig = plt.figure()
num_list=Final_dataset.columns.values.tolist()
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    column=num_list[i]
    sns.boxplot(x="label", y=column, data=Final_dataset, palette='Set2')
    plt.savefig('{}.png'. format(i))
    plt.show()
```

I need to produce one image that combine all attributes figures as in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYITq.png) rather than several figures. how Ican fix it? thanks, a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [subplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) function in matplotlib.

```py
nrows = 3 # decide how many you want
ncols = 4 # decide how many you want
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
num_list=Final_dataset.columns.values.tolist()
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    column=num_list[i]
    sns.boxplot(x="label", y=column, data=Final_dataset, palette='Set2')
    plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, index = 1+i)
plt.savefig('{}.png'. format(i))
plt.show()
```